# How to hide android SplashScreen or make it transparent when starting an app?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-styles

Recently I got a issue with Android S. When I start my app, it will show a splash screen before MainActivity, and the color of this splash screen was set to be the background color of MainActivity. Is there any way to make it transparent?

I tried to use the style below for my MainActivity, but it didn't work.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="TransparentSplash">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">0</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="TransparentSplash">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">0</item>
    </style>
</resources>